# how to style different pages differently in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have to add content to pages in a wordpress site. The problem is most of the page content have different styles. Do I need to create different css files for them?I read that page.php is the file which controls how each page is displayed. Do I need to add additional templates for other pages as shown here: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-have-a-separate-stylecss-for-each-page-template

Answer (score 1):

Styling is a very general question; You can change colors of certain areas only or create  completely different layout.

If it it is only font/color change -> open header.php of your theme and make sure that you have body class implemented.

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

Doing that, you will have different ID for each page on yours site. So if your site's entry is wrapped by a class .entry -> you can view the source of page -> get the id of body and add something like

```
#page-99 .entry a {color:#c00} /* new color for lin */
#page-99 .entry, 
#page-99 .entry p,
#page-99 .entry ul,
#page-99 .entry ol{color:#44} /* new color for static text */
```

Otherwise rather than loading different style files, i would probably create different [page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates) for each page.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create unique templates for each page.

Start with

```
<?php /* Template name: <name> */ ?>
```

The newly created template will appear on the right side of the content area where you will se "Template"

All the best,
Marten